# Activities not showing in Monitor & Manage

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

For one of my pipelines in ADF (v1), the activities already executed are not showing before a certain date in Monitor & Manage in the Azure portal.

However, if I go to that same Data Factory in the Azure portal, click the pipeline and find a slice, I can see all slices already executed. From here, I can run the slice again, - and then when executing that activity slice, it will show up in Monitor & Manage.

[image]

My problem with this is that I need to re-run hundreds of activities' specific slices. However, these slices are not showing in Monitor & Manage. And only in Monitor & Manage is it possible to re-run multiple slices, by marking those multiple slices. 
Any idea how I get those activities' slices to show up so I can re-run many slices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By design, it is **not possible** to see or run slices that are more than **45 days old**, from **Monitor & Manage**.

This is the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-using-azure-monitor#persist-data-factory-data

Note that you can still use the other part of the Azure portal to see and re-run older slices, but you can only run one slice at a time.

Not sure why these two parts use different API's to show slices, but that's how it works.

:-)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Have you tried changing the start time and end time?

Comment: Press F12, and click refresh button. In network tab, did you see any api call fail? If not, what is the response?

Comment: Also, please share a screenshot if possible.

Comment: No fails. Screenshot of what?

Comment: you mentioned the activities are not showing before a certain date. How long is the certain date? 15 days? 30 days?  If the activities are not showing out, there are three possibilities in my mind. 1. The data has been deleted, so if you check the api response, it will returns an empty array. 2. The api call failed due to some reasons. In that case, the status code won't be 200. Seems you said it is not this case. 3. The api returns the data successfully, but the ui didn't render it correctly. In this case, you could find the api returns an array with some data.

Comment: You could share the main screen of the Monitor and Management, or you could also file a ticket to support team if possible.

Comment: The result of the api method 'activitywindows' does not show more than what is shown in the UI, i.e. until a certain date. So the missing activity executions are not being returned by the api. It must therefore render the UI correctly and does not fail in the api. I'm puzzles about it being deleted, because if I go to the pipeline in the Azure portal, click on the pipeline, the datasets and the date slices, I will find those slices that I cannot see in Monitor & Manage. So if it is deleted, it's deleted for the api, but not where the portal access is looking (different api, I suppose).

Comment: I am filing a support ticket.